# No descriptionFile in swagger-maven-plugin v3

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi, swagger-maven-plugin

I would like to migrate from swagger V2 to OpenAPI v3.

For swagger V2 I used the `com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin` plugin to generate my swagger file based on my code. I migrated to `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-maven-plugin` successfully. The only part missing is

```
<descriptionFile>src/doc/Swagger-Description.md</descriptionFile>
```

which I used in the old plugin to enrich the generated swagger file with some basic information.

I could not find any way to do so with `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-maven-plugin`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround (or even maybe as intended?) I added the MD text to the `configurationFilePath` file

```
openAPI:
  info:
  description: 'my MD description'
```